# Php redirct each data to each url

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database where I am storing data. Here every full link has a offer link. What I am trying to do? I want to **redirect every single data to every different URL**. But I failed.

*Example:1*

full link: http://localhost/LearnPHP/test/short2.php/redir&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

redirect link: google.com

*Example 2*

full link: http://localhost/LearnPHP/test/short2.php/redir&q=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.com

redirect link: youtube.com

***Someone when visiting the full link it should redirect each offer link***

**Database**

[image: database]

**Data Insert**

[image: PHP Data insert]

**PHP Code**
[image: PHP]

Comment: Code as image!!

Comment: Please edit your question and post text information as text.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy the code, and edited it. I don’t understand exactly what you are trying to do, but I just made some changes.

**Data Insert**

```
<?php 

include 'db.php’;

$first = "http://localhost/LearnPHP/test/short2.php/redir&q=";
$magic = urlencode($_POST["longUrl"]);

if($magic) {
    $finalUrl = $first . $magic;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO url (offer_link, full_link) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $magic, $finalUrl);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $finalUrl = '';
}

?>
```

In the above code, you can obviously tell I changed some things. First, I don’t have a checking statement inside the insert file. I have put it directly inside of the `db.php` file. I will post the code for it.

Next, I patched the vulnerability of mySQL injection (https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection) using prepared statements.

**db.php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "your_username";
$password = "your_password";
$dbname = "your_database_name";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: I want to redirect every single link to its own redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

For redirection part you can do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])) // if q param available
{
    $redirectUrl = urldecode($_GET['q']); // get link
    header("Location: $redirectUrl"); // redirect
}
```

I think that your problem is related to URL decode / encode: [LINK](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)